# 301 strip aspx from URL in IIS

Tags: iis

We changed our blog and now the url's don't have .aspx on the end of them but the URL is still the same otherwise. So

/blog/post/Using-Memory-Theory-to-Increase-Inbound-Results.aspx.

becomes

/blog/tips/using-memory-theory-to-increase-inbound-results

I'd like to 301 all of the old url's to the new link.

This is the rule I tried but it' redirects to the 404 page:

```
<rule name="Rewrite old blog to PHP format (compound route)" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url="([^/]+)/([^/\?]+)\.aspx$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?route={R:1}&amp;page={R:2}" redirectType="Temporary" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the rewrite script for the web.config that worked:

```
<rule name="Remove aspx" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="(.*)\.aspx\.?" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```